# How to solve a Windows 10 Task Scheduler error

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I have several tasks in Windows 10 that have recently failed. I've made no recent changes to the server. The tasks were working fine for years, and then started failing in December of 2017. I have the Scheduler tasks configured to run on System Startup.
When I check the History tab, I see:

```
Task Start Failed error: Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943712.
```

The task/General Tab is configured as follows:

```
Run whether user is logged on or not
Do not store password.
Run with highest privileges
Configure for Windows 10
```

The user account is "Admin". That user has no password and is an administrator.  It's in a secure room and secure subnet so I don't want to put a password on the workstation.

When I try to Run the task from the Selected Item / Run option, the scheduler logs the same error. Based on other posts, I've tried to edit the User Account, re-typing Admin and pressing the Check Names button. It shows the SERVERNAME\Admin, and does not prompt for a password.
I reviewed this [technet blog entry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/).  The security policy described was already disabled.

I checked the following entry in RegEdit and it was already set to zero.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa 
Value Name: disabledomaincreds 
Value Type: REG_DWORD 
Values: 0 (allow domain credentials to be stored)
```

How can I configure the task manager so that it does not produce this error?
Here's a sample XML of the task:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2015-04-20T16:55:15.6868362</Date>
    <Author>ParishServer1\Admin</Author>
    <Description>Oracle Backup</Description>
    <URI>\OracleBackup</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2015-04-20T17:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Sunday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-3901234542-781488667-2331813244-1001</UserId>
      <LogonType>S4U</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>true</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>true</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT1H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\SS_Library_Backups\LibraryBackup.cmd</Command>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\SS_Library_Backups</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: Can you export one or two of the tasks to XML and link them from the question? Given: 2147943712 = 80070520 = "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." you have found the most obvious answer, I would therefore suggest running the task with Process Monitor running.  Maybe issues with accessing files under C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA for example.

Comment: Hello HelpingHand.  Thanks for  your help.  I updated the original text with the task XML from the workstation in question.  How would I run a task with Process Monitor running?